# _far _near _cdecl _pascal in migration from VC6 to VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm migrating a project from VC6 to VS2019. As far as I know, _far _near are for the segmented memory model access, and _cdel _ pascal are for calling convention. All of them seem only existed in VC6 and older versions. For migration, is it safe to remove them like the #else block? Thanks!

Code:

```
   /* 関数タイプ  コンパイラ依存 */
    #ifdef  MSDOS
    #ifdef  _MSC_VER    /* MS-C Ver.6.0以上 */
    #define FAR         _far
    #define NEAR        _near
    #define CDECL       _cdecl
    
    #define LeafFunc    _fastcall _near /* nearコール  */
    #define NearFunc    _pascal _near   /* nearコール  */
    #define FarLeafFunc _fastcall _far  /* farコール   */
    #define FarFunc     _pascal _far    /* farコール   */
    #define register                    /* register宣言は無視 */
    
    #else   /* その他 */
    #define FAR
    #define NEAR
    #define CDECL
    
    #define LeafFunc
    #define NearFunc
    #define FarLeafFunc
    #define FarFunc
    #endif
```

NareFunc is used like the following code:

```
void NearFunc mmInit PT0() {
    //...
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to 9dan. I've corrected _far and _near in the post.

Comment: far, near is used for 16bit compatibility, so safe to delete. Cdecl, Pascal is calling convention: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: The [`__cdecl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=msvc-160) and [`__fastcall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fastcall?view=msvc-160) calling conventions are still supported, `__pascal` is obsolete and the official MS [recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/obsolete-calling-conventions?view=msvc-160) is to replace it with the `WINAPI` macro from `windows.h`.